# Difference between local, global and maximum solutions of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Unfortunately I can't find a good answer in 3 different books I have, and I dont get the difference, nor could I find any explanation online for this. Can someone be so kind to explain it to me or point me to the right direction?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A local solution is a solution defined on a neighborhhod of a point. The standard existence and uniqueness result proves the existence of a unique local solution (under certain conditions on the equation.)

A global solution is a solution defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$. $y(x)=e^x$ is a global solution of $y'=y$.

There are two different uses for the word maximal (which I suppose you meant instead of maximum.) I assume that you are refering to the fact that the solution is defined on a maximal interval, that is, $y\colon(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a solution that cannot be extended to any interval $(c,d)$ with $(a,b)\subset(c,d)$. $y=\tan x$ is a maximal solution of $y'=1+y^2$ on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Comment: How would you go about proving your solution global is their any theorem or lemma that can help.

Comment: The usual way is to show that the solution remains bounded on bounded intervals.